# AWS Lambda create folder in S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda that runs when files are uploaded to S3-A bucket and moves those files to another bucket S3-B. The challenge is that I need create a folder inside S3-B bucket with a corresponding date of uploaded files and move the files to the folder. Any help or ideas are greatly apprecited. It might sound confusing so feel free to ask questions.Thank you!

Comment: Just store them with the full path (eg `2020/09/foo.txt`) and it will work without creating a 'folder'.

Comment: I need a bucket with a date of copied files. I can't hardcode the name of a bucket. For example if I upload files to S3-A bucket today as 09/08/2020 then Lambda should create a bucket inside S3-B with a name as '2020-09-08' and do copy of files. I have file dump everyday and I need to sort them daily

Comment: Sure, it can do that. Should it use the date from the filename, from some data inside the file, or the "current" date? Also, should it use the date from a particular timezone? (I presume you are not located at UTC.)

Comment: I've tried passing 'current date' to the prefix but it didn't work. Could you please give a hint of how can I pass date to the path. Currently, I have this:                                                  current_date = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(“%Y-%m-%d”)
s3 = boto3.client(‘s3’)
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
    source_bucket = event[‘Records’][0][‘s3’][‘bucket’][‘name’]
    file_name = event[‘Records’][0][‘s3’][‘object’][‘key’]
    dest_bucket = ‘dest-bucket {}’.format(current_date)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a Lambda function that can be triggered by an Amazon S3 Event and move the object to another bucket:

```py
import json
import urllib
from datetime import date
import boto3

DEST_BUCKET = 'bucket-b'

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])


    dest_key = str(date.today()) + '/' + key
    
    s3_client.copy_object(
        Bucket=DEST_BUCKET,
        Key=dest_key,
        CopySource=f'{bucket}/{key}'
        )
```

The only thing to consider is timezones. The Lambda function runs in UTC and you might be expecting a slightly different date in your timezone, so you might need to adjust the time accordingly.

Comment: Thank you! I've figured it out last night before seeing your answer. It's working fine now. I'll vote for your answer because it gets the job done :).  Thank you again for your time !

Answer (score 4):

Just to clear up some confusion, in S3 there is no such thing as a folder. What you see in the interface is actually running the [ListObjects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) using a prefix. The prefix is what you are seeing as the folder hierarchy.

To help illustrate this an object might have a key (which is a piece of metadata that defines its name) of `folder/subfolder/file.txt`, in the console you're actually using a prefix of `folder/subfolder/*`. This makes sense if you think of S3 more like a key value store, where the value is the object itself.

For this reason you can make a key on a prefix that has not existed before without creating any other hierarchical features.

In your Lambda function, you will need to download the files locally and then upload them to their new object key (remembering to delete the old object). Some SDKS will have an automated function that will perform all of these steps for you (such as Boto3 with the [copy](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) function).

Comment: Thank you for a clarification. I was wondering if I can perform that without downloading files locally. I am using Boto3 already in my application to copy files from one bucket to another.

Comment: Unfortunately not, it will need to use local storage somewhere to migrate it as the 2 S3 buckets do not directly communicate with each other.