# How to specify S3 subfolder path in Lambda function

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I am trying to upload a file to a subfolder in S3 in lambda function.
Any suggestion for achieving this task. Currently I am able to upload to only the main S3 bucket folder.

```
s3_resource.Bucket("bucketname").upload_file("/tmp/file.csv", "file.csv")
```

However, my goal is to upload to a folder in bucketname/subfolder1/file.csv

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda create folder in S3 bucket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63745424/aws-lambda-create-folder-in-s3-bucket)

Comment: The method signature is `upload_file(Filename, Key)`. The Key will be `subfolder1/file.csv`. An S3 bucket is essentially a key/value store.

Answer (score 2):

Amazon has [this to say about S3 paths](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-folders.html):

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, and objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure instead of a hierarchy like you would see in a file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. It does this by using a shared name prefix for objects (that is, objects have names that begin with a common string). Object names are also referred to as key names.

In other words, you just need to specify the path you want to use for the upload, any directory concept only impacts how objects are enumerated and displayed, there isn't a directory you need to make like a traditional filesystem:

```python
s3_resource.Bucket("bucketname").upload_file("/tmp/file.csv", "subfolder1/file.csv")
```